# How can we tell an instruction is from application code or library code on Linux x86_64

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, shared-libraries, virtual-address-space

I wanted to know whether an instruction is from the application itself or from the library code.
I observed some application code/data are located at about `0x000055xxxx` while libraries and `mmap`ed regions are by default located at `0x00007fcxxxx`. Can I use for example, `0x00007f00...00` as a boundary to tell instruction is from the application itself or from the library?

How can I configure this boundary in Linux kernel?

---

Updated.

Can I prevent (or detect) a `syscall` instruction being issued from application code (only allow it to go through `libc`). Maybe we can do a binary scan, but due to the variable length of instruction, it's hard to prevent unintended `syscall` instruction.

Comment: Why do you ask? Your question is lacking motivation!

Answer (score 0):

Do it the other way. You need to learn a lot.

First, read a lot more about operating systems. So read the [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces* textbook](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/).

Then, learn more about [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

Read also Drepper's [*How to write shared libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) and Levine's [*Linkers and loaders*](https://www.iecc.com/linker/) book.

You want to use [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html) and [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

You probably want to parse the [/proc/self/maps](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) pseudo-file from inside your program. Or use [dladdr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html).

To get some insight, run `cat /proc/$$/maps` and `cat /proc/self/maps` in a Linux terminal

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to know whether an instruction is from userspace or from library code.

You are confused: *both* library code and main executable code *are* userspace.

On Linux `x86_64`, you can distinguish kernel addresses from userpsace addresses, because the kernel addresses are in the `FFFF8000'00000000` through `FFFFFFFF'FFFFFFFF` range on current (48-bit) implementations. See canonical form address description [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Virtual_address_space_details).

> I observed some application code/data are located at about 0x000055xxxx while libraries and mmaped regions are by default located at 0x00007fcxxxx. Can I use for example, 0x00007f00...00 as a boundary to tell instruction is from the application itself or from the library?

No, in general you can't. An application can be linked to load *anywhere* within canonical address space (though most applications aren't).

As Basile Starynkevitch already answered, you'll need to parse `/proc/$pid/maps`, or know what address the executable is linked to load at (for non-PIE binary).